# difficulties in xen server vm creation

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, xen

I'm executing  `xl create /etc/xen/config_vyos.cfg`
and getting an error:

```
Parsing config from /etc/xen/config_vyos.cfg
libxl: error: libxl_bootloader.c:637:bootloader_finished: bootloader failed - consult logfile /var/log/xen/bootloader.4.log
libxl: error: libxl_exec.c:118:libxl_report_child_exitstatus: bootloader [2309] exited with error status 1
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:1144:domcreate_rebuild_done: cannot (re-)build domain: -3
libxl: error: libxl.c:1610:libxl__destroy_domid: non-existant domain 4
libxl: error: libxl.c:1568:domain_destroy_callback: unable to destroy guest with domid 4
libxl: error: libxl.c:1495:domain_destroy_cb: destruction of domain 4 failed
```

/var/log/xen/bootloader.4.log file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/xen-4.6/bin/pygrub", line 874, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError, "Unable to find partition containing kernel"
RuntimeError: Unable to find partition containing kernel
```

my config file:

```
name="pvvyos"
vcpus=1
memory=2048   

disk=['file:/home/my/vyos-1.1.7-i586-virt.iso,hdc:cdrom,w',
      'phy:/dev/mapper/xen--srv-vyos,hda1,w']
vif=['bridge=xenbr0']
extra="console=hvc0"
on_poweroff='destroy'
on_crash='restart'
on_reboot='restart'
bootloader="pygrub"
```

What am I doing wrong?

After adding to config file `kernel = "/usr/lib/xen-4.6/boot/hvmloader"`
error changed to

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
Error opening /usr/lib/xen-4.6/boot/hvmloader in guest
```

but `/usr/lib/xen-4.6/boot/hvmloader` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Is `/dev/mapper/xen--srv-vyos` mounted on host (Dom0)? If yes, then that is a problem.

Unmount `/dev/mapper/xen--srv-vyos` and remove the partition if there is no data. Alternatively, if you have a free space left on physical volume, create a new logical volume by following below steps

1. **pvdisplay**    //to check free space left
2. **lvcreate** -L25GB -n ubuntu vg0    //Create logical volume ubuntu of 25GB
3. Open file /etc/xen/config_vyos.cfg and add

```
kernel = "/var/lib/xen/images/ubuntu-netboot/trusty14LTS/vmlinuz"
ramdisk = "/var/lib/xen/images/ubuntu-netboot/trusty14LTS/initrd.gz"
#bootloader="/usr/lib/xen-4.6/bin/pygrub".
```

4. xl create -c /etc/xen/config_vyos.cfg and Complete rest of the installation.
5. Open file /etc/xen/config_vyos.cfg and comment out the line start with kernel and ramdisk and uncomment bootloader.
6. xl create /etc/xen/config_vyos.cfg

Guest VM will boot properly.